# PhoneGapp FileTransfer Upload to S3 Returning Code=3 But Working to Heroku

Tags: amazon-s3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to upload an image from my ionic app to Amazon's S3 storage in an Ionic app directly via the [Cordova FileTransfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer).
The upload to my own Heroku server works, but the upload to the Amazon S3 server always fails with code=3 (Connection Error).

I am initiating the file transfer with this command:

```
ft.upload(imageURI, s3Config.url, succ, fail, options, true);
```

And following options:

```
ImageURI: cdvfile://localhost/temporary/cdv_photo_044.jpg
Upload URI: https://8d90n90q.s3.amazonaws.com
Options:    {
  "fileKey": "file",
  "fileName": "rndcdv_photo_044.jpg",
  "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
  "params": {
    "key": "cdv_photo_044.jpg",
    "AWSAccessKeyId": "AKIAIL6Q62UVPOESBLQA",
    "acl": "public-read",
    "policy": "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMS0wNFQwMDowMTo0MC4xMDhaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W1sic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCIka2V5IiwiIl0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiLCIiXSx7ImJ1Y2tldCI6IjhkOTBuOTBxIn0seyJhY2wiOiJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9XX0=",
    "signature": "BILWcf3I7IMjAXdTm0nh4Md81YI=",
    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close"
  },
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "chunkedMode": false
}
```

Things tried:

- I have validated that upload to s3 works by using curl.
- I have enabled CORS from all hosts on S3.
- Tried suggested solutions: chunkedMode & headers(connection close).

I have setup an example repository with the ionic app to try: https://github.com/benmarten/ionic-s3-upload-test
You can toggle between line [47](https://github.com/benmarten/ionic-s3-upload-test/blob/master/www/js/controllers.js#L47) and [49](https://github.com/benmarten/ionic-s3-upload-test/blob/master/www/js/controllers.js#L49) to see the difference (not working and working). Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution myself. With iOS9 there was a new policy mechanism introduced, hence one needs to update the ionic/phonegapp config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*"/>

<platform name="ios">
  <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSAppTransportSecurity">
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </config-file>
</platform>
```

To automatically populate these configurations to the iOS/Android configuration files, you can use this hook:
https://gist.github.com/marcocarnazzo/6f01a57d390e8fe3071f